# How do i handle data from MONEY column in SQL on the C# client?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Assume there are three variables `x, y` and Total. i have display `x` and `y` on a `datagridview` along with `total` so the customer can see and understand those values. Typically on form that the customer can see those values were put in two `decimal` points. Assume those `x, y` and `total` are columns of a table in **SQL server**. When i use `MONEY` as the type for those columns their values will have **four decimal points**. That is where my problem is, when i have displayed `x, y` and `total` on the form with **two decimal points** but the DB table columns actually have **four decimal points**:

1. To display values in **two decimal points** on the client do i need to round or truncate the four decimal points data?
2. When there is an operation like `total = x + y`, which values should i use for the operation (two decimal points values or four decimal points values)?

Comment: Perhaps, I misunderstand your question.  Could you provide examples of the number you are seeing that contain two and four decimal points?

Comment: You should obviously use the highest precision you can when doing mathematical operations on values. How you choose to display them is *entirely* up to you.

Comment: @Dweeberly please read the comment i made on AaronLS!

Comment: you can set the `Precision` and the `Scale` for decimal values in SQL.  `Precision` represents the total number of digits allowed, `Scale` represents the maximum number of decimal places.  The default in SQL is `(18,0)`, but you can configure these per table or per column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) When values are displayed two decimal points do i round the values
>   in to two decimal points or truncate?

You should do whatever makes sense for your business.  You'll need to speak to those who are knowledgeable of the data you are dealing with.  For example, if it were financial data, they may dictate that you use "bankers rounding".  .NET supports several forms of rounding.  I doubt there'd be any scenario where you'd truncate.

> When there is an operation like total = x + y, which values should i
>   use for the operation (two decimal points values or four decimal
>   points values)?

Do not round before performing arithmetic.  You should almost certainly use all available decimal points for arithmetic operations, and anytime you store results, store results to maximize conserving decimal points.  Only when you need to display to a user should you perform rounding.

If you performed rounding before performing arithmetic, or rounded the results and stored them for later use, then other operations that might summarize those results(such as averaging) would suffer from compound rounding error.

Comment: so for example, assume the rounded value of 234.567 is 234.57. if i do a percentage calculation on 234.567 it will give one answer and of i do it on 234.57 another. Sometimes customers have their own pocket calculators. If i made the calculation on 3 decimal point number and customer makes that from two decimal points he will question the value displayed on screen is incorrect

Comment: Why would the customer do a calculation on a 2 decimal number and think his calculation is wrong if a 3 decimal number is displayed? Likewise the inverse, if you display a 2 decimal number, calculate using the 2 decimal number.

Comment: This is a situation where I would have a conversation with the user about their expectation.  First, how did you end up with 234.567 in the first place?  If the value was originally entered as 234.56 then it will remain 234.56.  So at some point something happened, maybe interest accrued and added .007.  That would be where I'd focus the discussion, explaining that you are preserving those decimal places, and therefore they can't expect hand calculations to match.

Comment: 234.567 was not displayed on screen its value that stored in tag for calculations

Comment: 1) Change the form so it displays three decial places, or 2) add a disclaimer to the form, stating calculations based on <n> decimal places, and that displayed results may not be completely accurate.

Comment: @Greg typical retails systems display two decimal points if i can remember correctly!

Comment: At that point, I'd ask the user if we need to display all available decimal places to ensure that there is no confusion, or what can be done to bridge that gap.  The outcome of the discussion might also be that they want you, as per a business rule, to be rounding when interest accrues, or whatever action generates those extra decimal places.  It may be their policy that it should always be rounded to cents whenever interest accrues, and so you shouldn't even have had those extra decimals in the first place.

Comment: @greg Agreed. or change the calculation to do 2 decimal places. just be consistent with what is shown and what is calculated.

Comment: @PhillGreggan Yeh, I agree with Viper, that it may be safe for purposes of a calculation that is for display purposes only, to do the rounding to make hand calculations consistent.  It just depends on what the person viewing that percentage might be doing with it.

Comment: @AaronLS i really would like drag further or put new post, when i comes to pay by credit card, do we need to charge the amount with all decimal points or just two?